# how to resolve the error while using Scanner class in java

Tags: java, compiler-errors, java.util.scanner

I have created a class "My" in which i am simply taking input from user using Scanner class"

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class My
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
         int val;
         Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("Enter no = ");
         val= sc.nextInt();

         System.out.println("number " + val);
    }
}
```

But I am getting following errors:

```
My.java:1: cannot resolve symbolsymbol  : class Scanner
location: package util
import java.util.Scanner;

My.java:8: cannot resolve symbol
symbol  : class Scanner
location: package util
 java.util.Scanner scanner = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);

My.java:8: cannot resolve symbol
symbol  : class Scanner
location: package util
 java.util.Scanner scanner = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
```

Comment: Remove `<br>` in the code snapts

Comment: created Scanner object as "scanner" but used as "sc"

Comment: what is `sc` in your code??? change your line to `val = scanner.nextInt();`

Comment: After your edit your code no longer agrees with the error messages. Don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

You have created `Scanner` object as `scanner`, so change `sc` to `scanner` . Code will compile without any issues.

Also one more point, Instead of using below code

```
java.util.Scanner sc = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
```

You can directly use `Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)` since you have already imported Scanner class

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

Note: Use java1.5 and above to access Scanner class

Comment: Yes,I have updated it.I think there is some problem while importing Scanner class from util package because i am getting error for Scanner class not its object.please refer the first error.

Comment: Which version of java are you using?It should be 1.5 and above.  If that is not the case try setting the classpath

Comment: I am using j2sdk1.4.2_09, is it suitable or not?

Comment: Scanner class is available from java 1.5 , So use java 5 and above versions to access Scanner class

Answer (score -1):

```
`import java.util.Scanner;`
```

You can keep the name sc for your Scanner but change    `java.util.Scanner` in the body of your code to `Scanner` as you don't need to call the imported package to declare the object.

*Update*

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class My
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    int val;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter no = ");
    val= sc.nextInt();

    System.out.println("number " + val);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have imported java.utol.Scanner; class but still getting errors.